# go mysql SELECT query causes variable assignment error

Tags: mysql, go

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to query a mysql database.   I tried the following code:

```
rows, err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM t_users")
```

But running the `go run main.go` gives this error:

> cannot assign 1 values to 2 variables

But I don't get any errors for this:

```
rows, err := db.Query("DESCRIBE t_user")
```

How come my select statement is giving an error?

Comment: `QueryRow` returns one value, `Query` returns two.

Comment: Great that makes sense now, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mkopriva's response

> QueryRow returns one value, Query returns two